Using only field and vector space properties, prove that every subspace is the solution set of some system of homogeneous linear equations

Let $V = F^n$ be the space of column vectors.  Prove that every subspace $W$ of $V$ is the space of solutions of some system of homogeneous linear equations $AX = 0$.
Source: Artin Algebra.

I believe I have most of a proof (below), and need help completing it.
Of course, this is a result of basic linear algebra using e.g. the rank-nullity theorem.  Here, however, the question is to prove this for any field $F$ using only basic properties of fields and vector spaces, before linear algebra has been developed.  It is for this reason that the solution (page 1, 3.2 Problem 4, posted at Harvard, no less) is, IMO, incorrect: it assumes a field with things like orthogonality, which aren't defined for arbitrary fields.
Please do not give me the entire proof, but simply point me in the right direction for the next step.  I'm aware that proofs might (or might not!) be available, but want to prove it myself.
Partial Proof
Write $\newcommand{\null}{\operatorname{null}} \null(A)$ for the set of solutions of a system of homogeneous linear equations $AX = 0$.  Since $\null(A)$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, it is a vector space and has dimension at most $n$.
Consider a matrix $A_i$ such that  $W \subseteq \operatorname{null}(A_i)$. If $W \neq \null(A_i)$, there must exist a vector $v_i \notin W$ such that $v_i \in \null(A_i)$.  It suffices to show that this implies there exists a vector $a_i$ such that $a_iw = 0$ for all $w \in W$ but $a_iv_i \neq 0$.  We can then create $A_{i+1}$ by appending an additional row $a_i$ to $A_i$.  Every time we do so we’ve lowered the dimension of $\null(A_i)$ while preserving the invariant $W \subseteq \null(A_i)$, and so after at most $n$ times, we must have $W = \null(A_i)$.
How do I prove such a vector $a_i$ exists? If the field is the reals, it's easy: simply let $$a_i := v_i^\top.$$  But this won't work for arbitrary fields; for example, the complex.  I know for the complex we can do $a_i := v_i^H$.  But I need to show that, for an arbitrary field, such a vector exists.
I also explored non-constructive approaches, trying to do induction down on the dimension of $\null(A_i)$, but was not able to use this prove the existence of such a vector.

I would suggest thinking about the matrix $C$ whose columns are a basis for $W$. Then $b\in W \iff Cx=b$ is consistent. Now reduce $[C|b]$ to echelon form.

@TedShifrin I've been trying to work your suggestion but made little progress.  Is it a suggestion on how to construct vector $a_i$ as per my strategy? Or a suggestion to adopt a different strategy altogether?

A completely different strategy. I didn’t understand what you were doing.

I suggest to you a different approach. In particular, I suggest the following: choose a basis for $W$ and complete this to a basis of $V$. Then, take the coordinate functions from this basis. From this, you can obtain that $W$ is the zero set of some linear functions. Can you conclude from this?

First, I am not sure if you can use it, but thinking with matrices instead of linear transformations make this problem look harder than it actually is.
In any case, I would also suggest trying solving a much simpler problem first to get some intuition. Probably the simplest non trivial example is when $\dim(v)=2$ and $\dim(W)=1$. Try to write down the matrix equations you need to solve this problem (which have very few parameters), see how to get the solution, and then generalize it (which is what @CarlosLicea suggested, more or less)
